# Overwrite variable in seperate file React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

To have a constant app styling, I am storing the selected color value in redux store. Since not every component has access to this store (would produce too much overhead) I am using a seperate file which exports a variable containing the current selected style. Doing this you can easily use this style in every component.

```
export let primaryColor = '#ff00ff';
```

Is there a way to overwrite this value without implementing a class structure including getter and setter pattern?

Comment: without export a class for setting and getting a var, in my opinion having it in redux should be fine, and then you can updated the vars and having it in redux will not have any significant overhead you are worried about

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that

```
import {primaryColor} from 'path';

let returnMyColor = "#anycolor" ? "#anycolor" : primaryColor;
```